# submitted data can not be displayed in php

Tags: php, display

I have written a code in php that user can submit the data and after submission data will be displayed from database but its not display the data please help

its insert the dta in database successfully but not display it after submission please help where is the problem I don't know

here is the code

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
// This file provides the information for accessing the database.and connecting 
//to MySQL. It also sets the language coding to utf-8
// First we define the constants: 
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '*****');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'test');
// Next we assign the database connection to a variable that we will call $dbcon: 
$dbcon = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
// Finally, we set the language encoding.as utf-8

$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST["name"]);
$age=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST["age"]);

$add="INSERT INTO demo (name,age) VALUES ('".$name."','".$age."')";

$result=@mysqli_query($dbcon,$add);
if($result==TRUE)
{
exit();
}
$query="SELECT * FROM demo";
$rst=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($rst);
mysql_close();
?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">name</font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">age</font>
</td>
</tr>
<?php$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$f1=mysql_result($rst,$i,name);
$f2=mysql_result($rst,$i,age);
$i++;
}
?>
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
</tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_query` returns `true` on successful `INSERT`s. So in this case:

```
$result=@mysqli_query($dbcon,$add);
if($result==TRUE)
{
    exit();
}
```

You are telling PHP to exit your script if the query was successful. Since your data is successfully stored in your database, it will stop the execution of your script after this point, hence not displaying your data.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php